# Best way to call and manage response for many http request

Tags: c#, http, parallel-processing

I have a challenge, I need to call many http request and handle each of them.
How to do it, I don't want to wait for get response from one of them and then call next, how to assign a method for process response (like callback).
How can define callback and assign to each of them ?

Comment: What is your problem? what have you tried so far ?

Comment: how to define methods that handle response of http requests? and how to assign these methods to each of responses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) you can call that normaly(noneasync):

```
    public string TestNoneAsync()
    {
        var webClient = new WebClient();
        return webClient.DownloadString("http://www.google.com");
    }
```

2) you can use APM (async):

```
    private void SpecAPI()
    {
        var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
        //req.Method = "HEAD";
        req.BeginGetResponse(
            asyncResult =>
            {
                var resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.EndGetResponse(asyncResult);
                var headersText = formatHeaders(resp.Headers);
                Console.WriteLine(headersText);
            }, null);
    }

    private string formatHeaders(WebHeaderCollection headers)
    {
        var headerString = headers.Keys.Cast<string>()
                                  .Select(header => string.Format("{0}:{1}", header, headers[header]));
        return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, headerString.ToArray());
    }
```

3) you can create a callback and asign it,EAP.(async .net 2):

```
    public void EAPAsync()
    {
        var webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
        webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += webClientDownloadStringCompleted;
    }

    void webClientDownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // use e.Result
        Console.WriteLine("download completed callback.");
    }
```

4) you can use newer way TAP, cleare way (c# 5). it's recommended:

```
    public async Task<string> DownloadAsync(string url)
    {
        var webClient = new WebClient();
        return await webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
    }

    public void DownloadAsyncHandler()
    {
        //DownloadAsync("http://www.google.com");
    }
```

threading in this solution is't good approch.(many threads that pending to call http request!)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an Asynchronous programming model where you create **async** tasks and ***later*** use **await** keyword for the response.

So essentially you are not waiting for the first async call to finish, you'd just fire as many async tasks as you wish and wait to get a response only when you need the response to move ahead with your program logic.

Have a look at below for more details:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh696703.aspx

Comment: thank you, i run the example(on the link), it is slow! i need to call millions of http request. why it is slow to send request?

Comment: can you write some code? how to change this link code to solve my problem? .i am new in async.

Comment: @user2119213: Please explain in details about your requirements. Of course the calls will be slow, it depends on the network connection speed that you have at your end. Asynchronous programming model doesn't promise that your code will execute fast.

If you are trying to pull off this stunt of calling million web urls from your web application then you need to seriously revisit your design. Web url calls are network operations over http, so they take time. Your best bet is to write a windows service and have this asyn logic in your service.